# ng-show doesn't update when my radio model changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm checking to see if the value of my radio buttons exists and then showing. I have a few radio buttons with store names and when the person selects a button, it shows the people from that store.

The code works if I check for a regular string value

```
<!-- this works because 'West' isn't {{radio.model}} -->
<tr ng-show="user.store.indexOf('West') != -1" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Then I change the code to this

```
<!-- this breaks it. Selecting user buttons will show the store name as text where it says {{radio.model}}, but it won't ng-show the users -->
<tr ng-show="user.store.indexOf({{radio.model}}) != -1" data-ng-repeat="user in users">
```

This is my set of radio buttons

```
<label class="btn btn-primary" ng-repeat="store in global.user.store" ng-model="radio.model" btn-radio="store" uncheckable>{{store}}</label>
{{radio.model || 'null'}}
```

This is in my angular controller

```
// fixes the scope problem with ng-model
$scope.radio = {model: null};
```

I'll check the radio button and it'll say West on the page (where it says {{radio.model}})... but the West users don't become visible.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the {{ and }} brackets and it works. I realized the angular controller said $scope.radio = model: null, so I could access radio.model directly in the html without brackets.